# Do Refreshing Elf-stones exist?

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

I've read that there is a type of Elf-stone known as "Refreshing" that grants skill cooldown reduction. I've been saving my gear slots for these but I've never laid eyes on one. Are they real and just really rare, or are they like legendary firearms in Dead Island: coded in the game but unable to spawn, or am I just really unlucky, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

I've found one. It gives 30% skill cooldown reduction. I've run into it for the first time in 20-odd play-throughs at Legendary.
(I've also found my first Spider's Bane, both in Fornost. A good start, all things considered :-))

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or something for proof?